# How to get a unique constraint database exception in play framework

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, unique-constraint

I am working on play framework using jpa, I have a field with an unique constraint, after "try" to persist an entity with a repeated value, the framework shows an error page like this:

[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0Zl2.png)

When I try to catch this exception...

```
try{
        JPA.em().persist(nArtist);
    }catch(Exception e){
        form.reject("username","user already exist");
        return badRequest(create_artist.render(form));
    }
```

The page still shows the message... ( I tried already with rollback exception ).

Pdta: That JPA.em() is the only time I called the em.

Answer (score 0):

1. The call to `EntityManager.persist` does *not* guarantee changes to be flushed to the database immediately (which is the point at which constraint violations would emerge). If you want to force a flush, call `EntityManager.flush` right after `persist`
2. Do **not** use exceptions to handle conditions that could normally occur in your application and, above all, do **not** use the generic `java.lang.Exception`. The exceptions thrown from the persistence layer at persist time could mean a lot more things than the specific constraint violation that you're after